# cy.readFile asserts with null on Jenkins

Tags: javascript, jenkins, automated-tests, cypress

I got the assertion error in Jenkins when I try to compare the downloaded file content with needed one:

> Timed out retrying after 8000ms: expected null to equal '"User","Password","Currency"\n'

However, locally everything works fine, no errors.

My code:

```js
cy.get('li:contains("List")').click({ force: true })


let arr = ["\"User\"", "\"Password\"", "\"Currency\"\n"]
let b = arr.join(',')

cy.allure().step('Check downloaded report content')

let timezone = 2
let status = "APPROVED"
let downloadDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)
let downloadHours = (new Date().getUTCHours() + timezone).toString().padStart(2, "0")
let downloadMinutes = new Date().getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, "0")
let fileName = `./cypress/Downloads/${Title} ${Status} ${downloadDate}_${downloadHours}_${downloadMinutes}.csv`
cy.readFile(fileName, { timeout: 8000 }).should('eq', b)
```

Tried to specify encoding (utc-8, binary) in `cy.readFile(fileName, "binary" { timeout: 8000 }).should('eq', b)`. Also added `cy.wait(5000)` before `cy.readFile` but didn't help

Answer (score 1):

Never mind!
The problem was that I specified download folder name with Upper Case, so everything worked fine on my local machine because Windows is case-insensitive.

**Original:**

```
let fileName = `./cypress/Downloads/${Title} ${Status} ${downloadDate}_${downloadHours}_${downloadMinutes}.csv`
```

**Fixed:**

```
let fileName = `./cypress/downloads/${Title} ${Status} ${downloadDate}_${downloadHours}_${downloadMinutes}.csv`
```